# are javascript callbacks atomic

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to make sure fields in two independent third party databases hosted in different places are sync. I have the following generic node / express js code:

```
router.post ('url', function(req,res,next) {

    third_party_api_1.set_a (req.body.param, function(err, a) {

        third_party_api_2.set_b (req.body.param, function(err, b) {
            res.end()
        })

    })

})
```

If an end user post (param = 1) I expect (a = b = 1). If they post (param = 2) I expect (a = b = 2). If two users post (param = 1) and (param = 2) at the same time, will a and b in the third party databases always be equal? I understand that they can be 1 or 2 depending on timing, but I want to make sure it is either (a = b = 1) or (a = b = 2) but not (a = 1, b = 2) or (a = 2, b = 1).

In other words, will `set_a` and `set_b` be "atomic"?

Thanks!

EDIT #1:
"a" is a single value in a third party database, "b" is another single value in another third party database, I would like to have the user post a single value and my code replaces both a and b to that user value.

EDIT #2:
I have no direct control over the third party databases, I can only call a public api. Perhaps I need a mutex around the api calls? How can I implement that?

Comment: In your code, set_b is only called after the response is received from set_a. So it depends on how the remote API works.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking about “consistency” between two distributed systems not atomicity.

What you are asking is really more an architectural question rather than anything particular to JavaScript. If you are making calls against two different data stores, you would need some means to ensure these two endpoints are keep consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the answer is no. Even if you're code looked like the example below you wouldn't be safe because the calls to `setA` and `setB` could be interleaved with multiple callers.

```
router.post ('url', function(req,res,next) {
    api1.setA(req.body.param);
    api2.setB(req.body.param);
 });
```

You've also got to consider what happens if your application ends up deployed to a load balanced set of web servers.

It's difficult to recommend a solution without knowing more about the databases you're actually updating. Are they totally opaque or are the services in front of some kind of relational/document database?

Answer (score 0):

The question falls under database consistency where your architecture would be more responsible for maintaining the consistency across your distributed storage.

For example : Consider MongoDB with **sharded and replication deployment,** irrespective of your request the storage would be more responsible to create the consistent data after the last call your request.